# What's the alternative to using global variables in a callback function?

Tags: php, callback, global-variables

I have used PHP for a very long time, but not really used callbacks very much until quite recently. In the following code, the callback (the example is QueryPath, in case you're wondering, but it could be anything that accepts a callback) will add some link to an array:

```
// parse any product links out of the html
$aProducts = array();
qp( $html, 'a' )->each(function($index, $element){
    global $aProducts;

    $link = qp($element)->attr('href');

    $pregMatch = preg_match('@(.*)-p-(.*)\.html@i', $link, $matches);


   if( $pregMatch ) {
        $product_id = (int)$matches[2];

                if( !in_array($product_id, $aProducts) ) {
            $aProducts[] = $product_id;
        }
    }


});

    // print out our product array
    print_r( $aProducts );
```

What's the alternative to using `global $aProducts` (if there is one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `use`:

```
qp( $html, 'a' )->each(function($index, $element) use(&$aProducts) {
```

Note the `&`. This is needed, for otherwise you would be using a copy of the array. You can also *use* multiply values, just list them separated with a `,`. E.g: `use(&$aProducts, $someObj, &$someInt)`

PHP.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: It's not necessary to use & for objects though right? (I guess for copy functionality you do `clone $someObj`?)

Comment: No, for objects you don't need the &. It works the same, like when you would pass values to a function.

Comment: ;) I also didn't find a good link directly, I'll post it when I have one. For now maybe the general page on [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) will help?

Comment: If I understand the man page correctly, was this not possible before PHP 5.3, or was `use` in use before PHP 5.3, but just for anonymous functions?

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend you To Don't Use global  variable, instead put your code on a Class and Use $this  instead global  variable. it must Work